# Write to an existing excel file using Openpyxl starting in existing sheet starting at a specific column and row

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have been searching this question to write in an existing excel sheet starting from specific row and column however methods like [dataframe_to_rows](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html) is not writing from a specific position in a cell. 
I am now using a custom loop to write this however was wondering if there is a better approach. 
The loops works like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
file = "C:\\somepath\\some_existing_file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=False)
ws = wb['some_existing_sheet']

##Fill up the row and column needed
stcol = 5
strow = 5

## Writing the column header
for c in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    ws[get_column_letter(c+stcol)+str(strow)].value = df.columns[c]
## Writing the data
for r in range(0,len(df)):
    for c in range(0,len(df.columns)):
       ws[get_column_letter(c+stcol)+str(strow+r+1)].value = df.iloc[r][c]
wb.save(file)
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to write to specefic position in a cell. By any chance if this turns out to be duplicate question, happy to merge in the original thread. 
I do have another approach however with xlsx writer but this removes all other data from existing sheet

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') # opens Excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='abc', startrow=5, startcol=5,index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: There is no need to use `get_column_letter`

Comment: It is required to create a numeric loop for find each cell and assign values from each dataframe records. Not sure if I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
ws[get_column_letter(c+stcol)+str(strow)]
```

you can use

```
ws.cell(column=c+stcol, row=strow)
```